# mpi4py hangs when trying to send large data

Tags: send, freeze, mpi4py

i've recently encountered a problem trying to share large data among several processors using the command 'send' from the mpi4py-library. Even a 1000x3 numpy float array is too large to be sent. Any ideas how to overcome this problem?

thx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a simple solution. Divide data into small enough chunks...

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this same problem with `Isend` (not with `Send`). It appears that the problem was due to the sending process terminating before the receiver had received the data. I fixed this by including a `comm.barrier()` call at the end of each of the processes.

Answer (score 0):

Point-to-point send/recv of large data works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()

if rank == 0:
    data = numpy.arange(300*100000, dtype='f')
    comm.Send([data, MPI.FLOAT], dest=1, tag=77)
elif rank == 1:
    data = numpy.empty(300*100000, dtype='f')
    comm.Recv([data, MPI.FLOAT], source=0, tag=77)
    print data
```

Running this with two processors:

```
% ~/work/soft/mpich/bin/mpiexec -np 2 ./send-numpy.py
[  0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+00 ...,   2.99999960e+07
   2.99999980e+07   3.00000000e+07]
```