# Assertion failed error when using mpi4py Bcast to send large matrix

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I am using python with mpi4py to run parallel code on a computing cluster. I am getting the following error:

```
Assertion failed in file src/mpid/ch3/channels/mrail/src/rdma/ch3_rndvtransfer.$
[cli_15]: aborting job:
internal ABORT - process 15
```

I put in print statements to see where it is happening, and it occurs when I try to broadcast a large matrix (14x14x217) from 1 process to another of the total of 32 processes. The code works great when I run tests resulting in a smaller matrix, 14x14x61. Here are the relevant parts of the code (error occurs during the `comm.Bcast`):

```
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

...

recv_buffer=numpy.zeros((g.numbands,g.numbands,g.gridsize),'complex')
senddata=numpy.zeros((g.numbands,g.numbands,g.gridsize+6),'complex')
if rank==size-1:
    g.updateVHF(rank,size)  #perform calculation on part of data
    for i in range(size-1):
        comm.Recv(recv_buffer,source=i,tag=0)
        g.VHartree=g.VHartree+recv_buffer[:]

        comm.Recv(recv_buffer,source=i,tag=1)
        g.VFock=g.VFock+recv_buffer[:]

        g.updateBasis()
        senddata[:,:,0:g.gridsize]=g.wf
        senddata[:,:,g.gridsize::]=g.wf0

else:
    g.updateVHF(rank,size)  # perform calculation on part of data
    comm.Send(g.VHartree,dest=size-1,tag=0)
    comm.Send(g.VFock,dest=size-1,tag=1)

comm.Bcast(senddata,root=size-1)  # broadcast to everyone else
if rank != size-1:  # rank==size-1 already has updated values
    g.wf=senddata[:,:,0:g.gridsize]
    g.wf0=senddata[:,:,g.gridsize::]
```

I found the following: http://listarc.com/showthread.php?4387119-Assertion+failure and [mpi4py hangs when trying to send large data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21528275/mpi4py-hangs-when-trying-to-send-large-data), which suggest that there is some size limit to the data that can be sent between processes. Am I correct in thinking that my error due to reaching some limit in the size of data transfer? If so, why does it occur only during the `Bcast` and not the other `Send`/`Recv` communications, since the matrices involved are almost the same size?